# Python for loop returning IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I have just recently began to learn python. I am trying to find the lowest integer in the digits list. Instead I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:/Python/untitled/08_python.py", line 32, in <module>
    if digits[e] < temp:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I realize that you can use min(digits) but I thought I would challenge my knowledge so far. I most likely made a simple mistake and am not diagnosing it properly. If I throw 0 in the list everything works fine.

```
digits = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

low = 0
temp = 0
for e in digits:
    if digits[e] < temp:
        low = digits[e]
    temp = digits[e]

print(low)
```

Comment: `e` is each of the digits in the list. You can't just use those as index into `digits` again, you don't have a `digits[10]`.

Comment: Just use `if e < temp` and `temp = e`. You don't need both a `temp` and `low`, by the way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`for e in digits` iterates over the *contents* of the list directly. You don't need to use `digits[e]` at that point since `e` is already the value, not the index. And that's also why it fails, since `digits[10]` is past the end of your list.

Other minor note - your code will only work with positive numbers since you're starting with `low = 0`; if the list has negatives only you'll still get `0` as your result.
One way to avoid that by setting it to `None` at the beginning and checking for that as well:

```
low = None
for e in digits:
    if low is None or low < e:
        low = e
print(low)
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know how to declare an integer as none

Comment: Python is dynamically typed; you don't need to declare variables and you can assign the same name to different types. `low` is not an integer or a `None`, it's just a name referring to one of those things. [Here](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html) is a really good article on that.

Comment: @RylandScarth: the code doesn't declare anything. Python variables don't care about the type of object that are assigned to them; `low = None` is *just an assignment, not a declaration*. So first `low` is bound to the `None` object, then later it is bound to an integer, and the variable never cares. You can assign a string to it later on if you like.

Answer (score 2):

`for e in digits` translates roughly as:

```
for i in range(0, len(digits)):
    e = digits[i]
```

So your code becomes:

```
for i in range(0, len(digits)):
    if digits[digits[i]] < temp:
```

When:

- i == 0, digits[i] == 1, & digits[digits[i]] == 2
- i == 1, digits[i] == 2, & digits[digits[i]] == 3
- i == 8, digits[i] == 9, & digits[digits[i]] == 10
- i == 9, digits[i] == 10, & digits[digits[i]] raises `IndexError`

---

When you add in `0` at the start of the list, then the identity `i == digits[i]` holds for all indices, and your code doesn't crash, but it is still doing the double indexing, which is not what you want.

Answer (score 2):

You have several problems in your code:

- You are making the assumption `e` is an index. It is not, it is the *actual value* from your `digits` list. Your list has indices from 0 through to 9, so when `e == 10` (the last element) you'll get an `IndexError`; there is no `digits[10]`.
- You set `temp` and `low` to `0`. None of your values in `digits` are lower than `0` so you'll never find anything where `e < temp` will be true. You'll need to pick a *very high* value instead. `float('inf')` is an artificial 'highest' value (infinity), that works really well for such tests; *any* integer value is lower than infinity.
- You don't need both a `temp` and a `low` variable. You only need one or the other to test if a later value is lower still.

Working code, then, looks like this:

```
low = float('inf')
for e in digits:
    if e < low:
        low = e
```